# You know nothing Jon Snow

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why does everybody keep saying to Jon Snow that he knows nothing in *Game of Thrones*? What do you think he knows?

Comment: *"What do you think he knows?"* - Uh, wut?

Comment: Iam gonig to tell something and i hope its what is going to happen; what jhon snow knows is -OK here we go - how to talk to white walkers and convince them to be his army in this way he is going to be king of the north and the ruler of the seven kingdoms.

Comment: Then you might want to substantiate your question a bit. Asking us what we think Jon Snow knows is entirely unclear, broad and opinion-based.

Comment: Everybody? I thought it was just Ygritte?

Comment: While GRRM may be using it to imply something bigger, I simply take it as a recurring theme that Jon Snow knows a lot less about the world than he thinks he does. As one of, if not THE, story's main protagonist(s), he is slowly becoming more worldly as the story progresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(IMO)
What doesn't Jon Snow know? Too damn much!

(I've decided to spoil mark this answer. Even though it is my opinion, it may reveal information not yet known by other viewers, understanding that GoT is an unusual case.)

Old Nan recounted a story to Bran about an old king of the North (a progenitor of the Starks) who fell in love with a Queen of the White Walkers. He became King of the North. His abilities (to understand the language of, as well as understand the ways of) the WW's has been passed down through his descendents.

> Jon is not the bastard of Ned Stark and Ashara Dayne, but rather Lyanna Stark and Prince Rhaegar Targaryen, making him both heir to the Stark line's abilities as well as to the Targaryen's.
>  When Jon meets a dragon, those abilities will be re-kindled in him. I believe he will have the White Walkers following him while riding atop a Dragon.

Let's recap:

1. Who his father really is..
2. Who his mother really is..

> 3. That he will be able to understand, and lead, the White Walkers..
>  4. That he will be able to understand, and lead, Dragons..

(#2 is (sort of) common knowledge, at this point, although who he *believes* his mother is, may not actually be so...)

Comment: Likewise, if the situation hasn't changed entirely since I last read about this matter, you might either want to point out in the answer that this theory is still largely conjecture on your (or the internet's) part or provide some kind of proof for this.

Comment: @CGCampbell Sure, there's nothing wrong with speculation, especially for a question that's likely to not get reopened anyway *because* it solicits opinions only. But even in this case at least *pointing out* that this isn't all hard truth is beneficial.

Comment: I'm of the belief that the [Night's King](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Night%27s_King) was of unknown heritage. Only hinted at being a Stark by Old Nan (whom in her stories, almost everyone was a Stark). The Night's King could have also been a [Bolton, Magnar of Skagos, a Flint, A Norrey or a Woodfoot](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Night%27s_King#A_Storm_of_Swords). In fact, Stannis with Melisandre seems to fit the bill moreso than Jon does.